# Fortran : even using a module, the compiler answers error #6404

Tags: types, module, fortran

In the main program, a module is declared with many variables as follows :

```
module my_module

integer kindi
parameter (kindi=4)

integer (kindi) my_var_from_module

end module my_module
```

In a particular function, the module is used, but the only variable from the module seems to have no type :

```
subroutine my_function(param1, param2)

use my_module
implicit none

integer (kindi) param1, param2

print*, 'my_var_from_module = ', my_var_from_module

end function
```

Also, I've tried to declare a variable locally with the same name, but it replaces its value.

The result is the message from the compiler :

```
error #6404: This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type.
```

Comment: Please show how the relevant declaration in `my_module` of `my_var_from_module`.  Ideally please create a [mcve].  And also note that `param1` and `param2` haven't an explicit type declared so show where the compiler is pointing to in its complaint.

Comment: The software is maid of subroutine of more than 6000 lines, so I can hardly make a minimal reproducible example

Comment: Yes you can - remember Stackoverflow is a collaborative efforts and you tend to get out as much as you put in. To create a minimal reproducible example pick out the relevant bits of the larger code, create a simple driver for those bits, and then compile that. At that point either a) You have the same problem in which case show us the small, cut down version or b) The problem will have "gone away" which should help you solve the problem yourself

Comment: Let me try your idea...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal example did work.

So I removed the main program `.o` file where the module is declared and it solved the problem...

Final explanation : the computer that stores the code and the one that compiles/executes it are not the same. So to test modifications, everything needs to be moved from a computer to the other. However, a parasitic `my_module.mod` used to be in the development file system and `make` wouldn't replace it. For this reason, if the main file had not been modified at the same time as the subroutine, the variable wasn't known from the compiler who was using an old version of the `.mod` file.